# Defining the size of a vector inside a class in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class named "Circle" which is defined by the number of points on its circumference. Each point, in turn, is defined by its x and y value. In order to create individual points, I have a class like this:

```
class Point{
public:
    double x; // x position
    double y; // y position

    // Default constructor
    Point()
    : x(0.0),y(0.0){
    }
};
```

which basically creates a point. I create the "Circle" from these points by way of this class:

```
class Circle{
public:
    vector<Point> points; // points with x and y coordinates

    // Default constructor
    Circle()
    : points(0.0) {
    }
};
```

which creates the circle as a combination of points.

The number of circles and the corresponding points on each of them are already pre-determined. Let's say there are M circles and N points on each of them, for the sake of argument. So I create these entities like this:

```
vector<Circle> circles(M);
```

and this is where my problem begins, because I want to pre-determine the size of the vector "points" for each of my "circles" objects like:

```
vector<Point> points(N);
```

tl;dr How can I define the size of a vector inside of a class? It really doesn't matter whether I do it from inside of the class or not. All I want is to be able to determine the size of "points" vector for each "circles" object to N.

Comment: `Circle() : points(N) {}` or `vector<Point> points = vector<Point>(N);` (the latter requires C++11.)

Comment: if the number is fixed, juancho's solution works. Otherwise (it is decided later), go for a setter method

Comment: If number of points is fixed at compile-time for all circles, you can use `std::array<Point, N>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the constructor of class Circle with a parameter

```
class Circle{
public:
    vector<Point> points; // points with x and y coordinates

    // Default constructor
    Circle( size_t n ) : points( n ) 
    {
    }
};
```

And then declare the vector of Circle

```
vector<Circle> circles( M, N );
```

If you want that the constructor would be explicit as for example

```
explicit Circle( size_t n ) : points( n ) 
{
}
```

then you have to define the vector the following way

```
vector<Circle> circles( M, Circle( N ) );
```

Also you can make the constructor default

```
    Circle( size_t n = 0 ) : points( n ) 
    {
    }
```

Comment: What does making it "explicit" mean?

Comment: @ozdm it means that an integer object can not be implicitly converted to an object of type Circle. Compare the two vector definitions in my post.

Comment: Many thanks, it seems to work for me. However, I really don't understand how calling vector<Circle> circles(M,N); creates an N-sized points vector within the class circles like points(N). It occurs to me that, we didn't do anything to separate M from N in the call. How does the compiler separate the M from the N inside circles(M,N)?

Comment: @ozdm  The vector defined of class Circle. So the second parameter of the vector constructor has type Circle. However you passed on N. So the compiler searches whether it can call an appropriate constructor of class Circle that has one parameter of integral type and which it can call implicitle. And there is such a constructor in class Circle.